# iOS app lost 32 bit support after update

Tags: ios

I recently uploaded an update to an app from late 2014. I changed the base SDK to iOS7 and added frameworks through CocoaPods including One Signal. Once the app was approved by Apple and published, when the users try to update, they were getting an error "Unable to Purchase", "This app is not compatible with your device".

I then noticed that in the list of supported devices on the App Store, the app offered support for iPhone 5S and later and iPad Air and later; meaning that the app is only supported on devices with a 64bit processor.

`VALID_ARCHS` are `"armv7 armv7s arm64"`

architectures is set to `ARCHS_STANDARD` `armv7 arm64`

and required device capabilities is `armv7`

Also when I run through xCode, the app runs on the devices which are not supported on the App Store.

Any idea on how I could fix this?

Comment: Thought I'd tag things iOS related - thanks for the fix and link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from checking the valid architecture, you will also need to check the Build Active Architecture Only from the Target > Build Settings. You can expand this to reveal Debug and Release modes. In Debug it's ok for this to be Yes, but in release, in this case, this would need to be No. If yes, the build will also happen for the connected device's architecture, so if you want to make sure that xcode builds the app for all architectures required, make sure to set this to No for release. For Debug it's ok for this to be yes cause you would only need to build for the device you are testing on, and this would save you some time.

Apart from the above, you might also need to remove RequiredDeviceCapabilities that are related to architecture from the Plist file.